# python fast writing of a variables name and value

Tags: python

I am porting some code from matlab to python and i see that I miss fast variable content inspection and printing of the matlab (in scripts) like shown below.

```
a=6

a =

     6
```

Same thing in python:

```
a=6 ; print "a = \n",a
a =
6
```

In a matlab script if you write an assignment like shown above, without a semicolon at the end, it prints just like that. You can write the whole script like that, and later shutdown all those lines with semicolons. It is very helpful for early debugging purposes.

Just now, I scanned all lines with assignments, and put prints like

```
; print "a", a
```

at the end of them. I immediately saw the problem with the code.

Is there a way to type less for this purpose?

Comment: So you want the REPL to print out what you typed into it?

Comment: First, if you just type `a` at the prompt, it'll show you the value of `a` (it's the `repr`, not the `str`, but for ints that doesn't matter). Is `In [9]: a\n6` worse than `a =\n6`?

Comment: I updated my question to make it more clear. I miss this not in interactive prompt but during writing a script. I develop with pydev by the way.

Comment: So you want every assignment anywhere in your script to print something out? So if you write `for i in range(1000): a = func(a, i)`, you want 2000 lines of output?

Comment: @abarnert: obviously not all. But when I need to debug, I sometimes need to write a lot of print statements here and there.

Comment: @ozi: So, how do you expect it to know which assignments you want to trigger an output, and which you don't?

Comment: As a side note, given that you're trying to do matlab-type stuff, if you're not using numpy, you may want to consider it. It lets you do element-wise array operations, matrix operations, etc. in one line instead of a loop—and it's usually about 10x as fast as the loop, too, and uses about 25% the memory (so you can work on larger data sets without manually paging stuff to disk).

Comment: @abarnert: thx I am using numpy. There was something about logging on this debugging business in python, but I just could not work on that. That might be the way to go with python.

Answer (score 1):

The ipython (or plain python) interactive interpreter already shows you the value of anything you type into it.

The only reason you don't see anything for `a=6` is that, in Python, assignment is a statement, not an expression, and therefore it doesn't have a value.

But if you just type `a`, that's an expression, with a value, and it will show you the value:

```
In [8]: a=6
In [9]: a
Out[9]: 6
```

If that's not good enough, and you want it to automatically show you the name and value for any assignment statement… that's not *impossible*, but it's much harder than it's worth.